# Conky goes full screen on auto start, but not when opened regularly

Tags: conky

I've got Conky installed on 18.04 and I've been messing around and customizing my config file.  I've got it set up and it runs fine.  I've got it set up to bind to the right side of my screen which is where I want it.

The issue I have is when I configure Conky to start on boot.  I'm using the standard startup applications to autostart.  I made a bash script that sleeps for 20 seconds and then starts conky, and I pointed the startup applications to that script.

Conky does autostart after boot, but when it starts it takes up the whole screen and also some of the information that I've configured Conky to display ends up looking like C code.

When I run a killall and restart, it then comes up and works fine.

So the issue is something with the auto start up and I'm not 100% sure what.  Otherwise Conky runs fine.

I've made a new config file, deleted the autostart and created a new one, but nothing is working so far.  Any ideas?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Can you [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1087160/edit) your question and share your autostart configuration?

Comment: Are you talking about the bash script?  I'm using the standard "Startup Applications" application that comes with Ubuntu and I created and added the bash script to the list of programs to run after boot.  If you're asking about the bash script, then it's: #!/bin/bash sleep 20 conky

Answer (score 0):

So it seems like the issue was that Conky would sometimes start before I had my internet connection established.  I'm not 100% why not having an internet connection would cause Conky to go full screen though, but I think the reason I was seeing weird C code type information was because there was no internet connection.

I've noticed that as long as I have an internet connection established before Conky starts, then everything runs fine.